# Custom Action Location on Central Administration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, central-administration, application-pages

I want to add a custom admin application page in central administration. I successfully deployed a custom Group on the default Central Administration Page with the Elements.xml. But now, I have some problems deploying a new "Group Location" to add some new groups to this new created admin application page.

So now... I think I have to register a new "Custom Action Locations" like

- Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Applications
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Backups

or something like [MSDN: Default Custom Action Locations and IDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb802730(v=office.15).aspx#sectionSection2)

But I have absolutly no idea, how I have to manage this. I cant find more informations for adding this "locations" on technet or msdn.

Did someone figured this out?

Code I want to have (or something like that)

```
<CustomAction Id="MyOwnID" GroupId="MyOwnGroup"
  Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.MyOwnPageLocation"
  Sequence="10"
  Title="Foo" Description="Bar">
<UrlAction Url="_admin/MyCustomPage.aspx" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uff... figured it out!

On Application Page in PlaceHolderMain add the folowing code:

```
<SharePoint:FeatureLinkSections runat="server"
    ID="mrxPP"
    CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="4"
    Location="mrxpp.Administration.Default"
    LinkSectionControl="LinkSectionLevel2.ascx" />
```

The location, which you define here is the new location, where you can bind groups or links or something like that!

I found this [Blogpost](https://bramdejager.wordpress.com/2011/09/30/build-your-own-custom-administration/), which helped me.

This cost me five days... grml!